# How to handle SVN externals when migrating to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm currently migrating our SVN repositories to git and I'm not sure how to handle the SVN externals.

I normally would clone and add them as git submodules since I want to keep track of the changes and also push commits to the submodule's repo. Unfortunately git by default clones the whole repo but I only need a subdirectory of it.

The external repo looks similar to this.

```
external/bar/lib/
external/foo/
external/foo.sln
...
```

So I thought about using `sparse-checkout` to only clone the `external/bar/lib/`directory to my main project but I'm not sure If I still can do normal git operations like `commit`, `push`, `pull` and `branch` in the submodule when using a sparse checkout or how to handle the case when I also want to include `external/foo/` in my main project.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, each relevant folder of `external/` should have been `git-svn` exported in their own individual Git repository:

```
external/bar/lib/ => lib.git
external/foo/ => foo.git
```

That way, no need to worry about sparse checkout (which would indeed limit the ability to push back commits)